# How to use singleTileImageryProvider with cesium?

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

I am currently using cesium to display layers from WMS server on my app, with angular.
For the moment, i am using WebMapServiceImageryProvider that gives me layers with tilling scheme.
To increase performances i would like my app to request a unique tile for the whole image.
I saw that SingleTileImageryProvider is existing on cesium.
Could you tell me if the structure is the same ? Or if I need to change something in particular to make it works ?

Comment: do not undetstand well this "To increase performances i would like my app to request a unique tile for the whole image."

Comment: In fact, my server is a bit long. That’s why sending many requests for tiles is not efficient. I would like to load a unique tile for the entire map, to have just one request to the server

Comment: Any ideas to help me ?